# Docker Open VPN Connected But Not Access Internet in docker

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, networking, openvpn

The openvpn connection is successful. But I make a call to the internet. I could not know there is a problem in the network structure. At the request of your help.

This Sample Repo: https://github.com/mesutcakir/openvpn-docker-sample/

My result Routes

```
# ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.53 dev tun1
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.53 dev tun1
10.8.0.53 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.54
94.23.57.8 via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.53 dev tun1
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.2

# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
5: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.54 peer 10.8.0.53/32 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
106: eth0@if107: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```